# How to Move selected text Left or Right

Tags: webstorm

I can't believe I can't find a way in Webstorm that when you highlight code, then move it right or left as a group (tab left or right, moving it over left or right).

Is there a way to do this?  I can't find one.  I need to shift several lines of code in JSON to tab and make it read better from withing Webstorm as just one example.  Most editors have this capability!  unless I'm just missing it, this is a huge hole in Webstorm that is fundamental that is simply not there!

On top of this I've also noticed that if you put your cursor at the beginning of a line of code and then do Shift + Home to highlight the empty space before it, typically in most editors you can hit tab and start moving it back from the farthest point left back to right.  In webstorm, when you highlight the empty space to the left of a starting line and hit tab, it starts tabbing from the the start of the line, not from the first empty space.  I find this bizarre and very frustrating.

Answer (score 14):

select a code region and hit Tab (Edit | Indent Selection) or Shift+Tab (unindent)